# Can I build a VPN on top of Tor?

Tags: networking, security, vpn, privacy, tor

If I understand correctly, the Tor client works as a combination of a proxy server and application plugins (such as the Firefox Torbutton) that enable use of the proxy and contain additional application-specific privacy features (such as suppressing cookies, sandboxing JavaScript, turning off Flash).

That works very well with applications that support it (such as Firefox). But is there a way to establish a VPN over Tor, so that my whole Wifi network can be protected, including applications that do not support proxy configuration and devices like iPod touches?

Comment: JS is "sandboxed" by default.

Comment: @curiousguy: Not if by sandboxed I mean "do not load all those tracking cookies and Facebook widgets without my explicit permission". Or just "do not start the JS until I say so".

Comment: "_do not load all those tracking cookies and Facebook widgets without my explicit permission_". That is not what "sandboxed" means. A sandbox is an isolation feature. JS loaded from one site cannot read content from other sites, or from local files: that's isolation. And a tracking cookie is just a cookie; the browser cannot tell a tracking cookie from another cookie. You can blacklist several domains known to send tracking cookies, but it is not an isolation feature.

Comment: Take a look at NoScript. You can restrict the JS that runs quite effectively. Does not matter how you call it. Not loading all the external JS also prevents most of the tracking cookies. And any way this is completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: "_Take a look at NoScript._" It is a very useful extension (and it has an HTTP sandboxing feature). "_Not loading all the external JS also prevents most of the tracking cookies._" Websites can still "track" you with other means. "_Does not matter how you call it._" Using the proper terms matters a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Privoxy to act as a HTTP to SOCKS gateway on to the tor network.

From what i can tell OpenVPN supports http proxy OpenVPN

maybe with the use of a wrapper like torify (included in tor) and socksify part of Dante can support direct SOCKS access.

I would suggest pre-defining a tor exit-point for the sake of stability.

Search for it with the following key words.

1. Dante
2. torify
3. 'Connecting to an OpenVPN server via an HTTP proxy.'

Comment: `torsocks` is easier to work with than `dante`.